# Query data in certain period of time, and group by each date and count total data for each date

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Need some help in linq

I want to achieve to get data, let say from '`2014-09-01`' to '`2014-10-30`'

and I want to group data, which have the same date, into 1 record, + count total occurence data for each date.

like this :

```
2014-09-01, 9 records
2014-09-12, 4 records
```

and so on..

Have tried this, I can get data within period and group by date, but not sure how to count data which occured within a given period for each date:

```
var data = CTX.application.Where(a => a.applied_date >= new Datetime(2014,9,1)  
                                   && a.applied_date <= new Datetime(2014,10,30)
                               .GroupBy(g => g.applied_date))
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var query = logs.Where(x => x.LogDate > new DateTime(2014, 09, 20) && x.LogDate < new DateTime(2014, 10, 12))
                                .GroupBy(x => x.LogDate).Select(x => new { LogDate = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6164lY).

Comment: Guess, you will have to select the date too, otherwise you don't know, what date belongs to what count :)

Comment: ah i guess this is what i want, so i only missing select part huh! thx for enlightment.

Comment: btw, my applied_date field it has datetime data type, can i ignore the second, and still group by date if it has the same date?

Comment: @HendraLim - Group by just the date in that case. Use - .GroupBy(x => x.LogDate.Date)